# Javafx organize buttons into two columns in flowpane

Tags: java, javafx

I have Pane `pane = new FlowPane()`, and that pane is inside a `ScrollPane`. I like to have two fixed columns in the pane where I can put buttons. I thought of the `setPrefWrappedlength` method, but I don't have access to it because my pane is of type `Pane` (I can't change this). Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: *"my pane is of type `Pane` (I can't change this)"* Why can't you change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it:

```
 Pane pane = new FlowPane();
 ((FlowPane) pane).setPrefWrappedlength();
```

or

```
  FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
  pane.setPrefWrappedlength();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
flowPane.setPrefWrappedLength(...);
Pane pane = flowPane ;
```

results in you having a reference `pane` of type `Pane` to a `FlowPane` instance whose `prefWrappedLength` is set to the value you want it set, which seems to be what you are asking for.